# How can I get lead id in process builder

Tags: process-builder

I'm created process builder for task object. When "lead" object task is closed I want to submit that record to approve. [image]

Actually What action I want choose next. How can get lead id? How can submit that record to approve?
Anyone please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with the Approval Process Action itself. Refer this link.... http://automationchampion.com/2015/05/25/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-25-auto-submit-record-into-approval-process/

Comment: But how to create task for lead object?

Comment: And how can I submit record for approve process after task is closed?

Comment: Creating Task For Lead Object, You cannot do this directly....Wait for a while for the Approve Process

Comment: Which action I want to choose for this?

Comment: Submit for Apporval, You want to Submit for Approval whenever the Task is Completed or Lead is Closed? On which condition you want?

Comment: But I'm choosing task object. And I want submit a lead record for approve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37752/discussion-between-subhash-and-jana-shree).